# Json Array to ND Json converter

Tags: c#, json

### Problem

- We have a tool which produces output as json array
- We have another tool which anticipates input as [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) (newline delimited json)
- I need to write a converter to transform json array to ndjson

#### Sample json array

```json
[
  {
    "Property1": true,
    "Property2": 0.1,
    "Property3": "text"
  },
  {
    "Property1": false,
    "Property2": 0.2,
    "Property3": "not text"
  },
  {
    "Property1": true,
    "Property2": 3.14,
    "Property3": "sample"
  },
  {
    "Property1": false,
    "Property2": -51.0,
    "Property3": "Property3"
  }
]
```

#### Sample ndjson

```json
{"Property1":true,"Property2":0.1,"Property3":"text"}
{"Property1":false,"Property2":0.2,"Property3":"not text"}
{"Property1":true,"Property2":3.14,"Property3":"sample"}
{"Property1":false,"Property2":-51.0,"Property3":"Property3"}
```

### Design

- Keep the converter as simple as possible

  - The converter should receive a source and a target file paths
  - The converter should not parse the data just reformat it
  - The converter should perform only some basic preliminary checks

#### Solution

- I'm comfortable to implement this with Json.NET

  - But I wanted to practice with System.Text.Json
  - So, I've decided to implement it with the latter
- I've added some comments to the code to help the reviewers

```cs
public static class JsonArrayToNDJsonConverter
{
    static JsonWriterOptions writerOptions = new() { Indented = false };
    public static void Convert(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        //Preliminary checks on source
        if (!File.Exists(sourcePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Source file is not found");
        using var sourceFile = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);

        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(sourceFile);
        if (jsonDocument.RootElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Array)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Json Array must be the source");

        //Not that graceful handling of file existence
        if (File.Exists(targetPath))
            File.Delete(targetPath);
        using var targetFile = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.CreateNew);

        using var targetFileWriter = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
        using var jsonObjectWithoutIndentation = new MemoryStream();
        foreach (var jsonObject in jsonDocument.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
        {
            //Write json object without indentation into a memorystream
            var jsonObjectStreamWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(jsonObjectWithoutIndentation, writerOptions);
            jsonObject.WriteTo(jsonObjectStreamWriter);
            jsonObjectStreamWriter.Flush();

            //Write memorystream to target
            var singleLinedJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonObjectWithoutIndentation.ToArray());
            targetFileWriter.WriteLine(singleLinedJson);

            //Reuse memory stream
            jsonObjectWithoutIndentation.Position = 0;
            jsonObjectWithoutIndentation.SetLength(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- always increase readability by using access modifiers.
- `Convert` is misleading, as you're reading and writing files, so describing the function is very useful to understand what's going on inside the method.
- `File.Delete(targetPath)` is not necessary, as you can use `FileMode.Create` which will create the file if not exists, and override it if exists.
- use `JsonException` instead of `InvalidOperationException`.
- `Utf8JsonWriter` should be outside the loop and it's `Disposable`.
- You can always use `File.ReadAllText` or `File.WriteAllText` instead for small to medium size files, as shortcut, however, for large files, I advice you using the proper streaming techniques (such as reading file in chunks) instead of reading everything.
- use the proper naming for objects such as `memoryStream` instead of `jsonObjectWithoutIndentation` and `jsonWriter` instead of `jsonObjectStreamWriter` to avoid confusion.
- use `Flush()` and `Reset()` all together with the `Utf8JsonWriter` to reset the stream. using `Flush()` alone would case some exceptions, as there are some stream counters are only reset by the `Reset()` and not by `Flush()` like `BytesCommitted`.
- you can use `FileStream` with `Utf8JsonWriter` directly, you just need to add a new line after each write.

here is a revised version that would shows the above points :

```
public static class JsonArrayToNDJsonConverter
{
    private static JsonWriterOptions _jsonWriterOptionNoIndentation = new() { Indented = false };
   
    private static byte[] _newLineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

    public static void ConvertJsonArrayFileToNDArray(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourcePath));
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetPath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetPath));

        if(!File.Exists(sourcePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Source file is not found");
    
        var sourceFile = File.ReadAllText(sourcePath);

        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(sourceFile);
        
        if (jsonDocument.RootElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Array)
            throw new JsonException("Json Array must be the source");

        using var targetFileStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create);
        using var jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(targetFileStream, _jsonWriterOptionNoIndentation);
        foreach (var jsonObject in jsonDocument.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
        {
            jsonObject.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
            jsonWriter.Flush();
            jsonWriter.Reset();
            targetFileStream.Write(_newLineBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Though I think it would be better if we just divide all that into several methods and inside one helper class, to give a better reusability. Also, it would be more effective if we just target `JsonArray` instead of `JsonDocument`  as you're only targting the `JsonArray` so using `JsonNode` and `JsonArray` would be enough.
Example :

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static JsonNode LoadFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Source file is not found");

        return JsonNode.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }

    public static void WriteToFileAsNDArray(this JsonArray jsonArray, string targetPath)
    {
        if (jsonArray == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonArray));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetPath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetPath));

        // remember this will throw an exception if the target path is invalid
        // if the file already exists, it'll be overridden
        File.WriteAllText(targetPath, jsonArray.ToJsonStringNDArray());
    }
}

public static class JsonNodeExtensions
{
    private static JsonWriterOptions _jsonWriterOptionNoIndentation = new() { Indented = false };
    
    private static byte[] _newLineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

    public static string ToJsonStringNDArray(this JsonArray jsonArray)
    {
        if (jsonArray == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonArray));

        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(memoryStream, _jsonWriterOptionNoIndentation);
        foreach (var jsonObject in jsonArray)
        {
            jsonObject.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
            jsonWriter.Flush();
            jsonWriter.Reset();
            memoryStream.Write(_newLineBytes);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
JsonHelper.LoadFromFile(sourcePath)
          .AsArray()
          .WriteToFileAsNDArray(targetPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the review. I've used the `Utf8JsonWriter` inside the loop, because I was not aware of the `Reset` call and I couldn't reuse the writer for multiple `JsonElement`s.

Comment: *use the proper naming for objects such as memoryStream instead of jsonObjectWithoutIndentation* > I can argue with that. Naming a variable to `memoryStream`, `stringBuilder`, `jArray`, etc... does not tell anything about the data that is stored inside them. But I think this is more like a personal preference than following some well-known guidance.

Comment: @PeterCsala `JsonObject` is a class under `System.Text.Json`  what I meant is just to use a naming that is related to the object that is currently used.  so `jsonObjectWithoutIndentation` at first glance, would give an impression that it's a `JsonObject` and not a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @PeterCsala I doubt that both `System.Text.Json` and `Json.NET` with their `Converter` would do you any good for NDArray. As this would need to alter the serializer behavior, and I don't think it would be a wise idea to go that far.  So, your approach is the easiest and safest way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

- If `sourcePath` is `null` the method would throw an `FileNotFoundException` as well, because `File.Exists()` will return `false` in such a case.
  You would have serious problems to find the cause of a `FileNotFoundException` if you would see in the filesystem that the file exists but your code is telling otherwise because you assume having passed the correct filename.
- If you are sure that `targetPath` is a valid filename, you won't need to call `File.Exists()` because `File.Delete()` won't throw an exception if the file doesn't exists.
- Calling `MemoryStream.SetLength(0)` will set its `Position` to `0` as well.
- Using braces `{}` althought they migth be optional will prevent hidden bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Since I haven't received any comment on the usage of the System.Text.Json I assume that part is okayish.

Comment: I can't tell you that because I never used System.Text.Json.

Answer (score 1):

### Parameters

It's more natural and flexible to just receive the input and output streams as parameters. The conversion doesn't really care if it's reading the JSON from a file or some other source (e.g. HTTP request).

### Memory Usage

Loading the entire JSON into memory is not ideal if the content is sufficiently large. This transformation can be easily done with \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ memory by using streaming techniques.